# getting msvcr100.dll not found errors, but the file msvcr100_clr0400.dll is present in both System32 and SysWOW64

Tags: windows-10

As the title says. I've tried installing and reinstalling every vc++ distribution. Haven't done a registry edit yet. On searching the two folders, I did find that variant of the file, but the error persisted. Should I go ahead and try out registry tweaks? Or is there some extra step I'm missing?

Incidentally, this was on a fresh installation of windows, so is it possible that it didn't install properly?

Comment: I know you said you installed every vc++ redistributable, but are absolutely sure you've installed both the [32-bit](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=5555) and [64-bit](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=14632) versions of the 2010 vc++ redistributable?

Comment: @n8te that was exactly it, figured it out finally. If you type that out that as an answer, I'll select it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For errors indicating `msvcr100.dll` is missing, you'll need to install the **Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 Redistributable Package**

On a 64-bit system go ahead and install both the 32-bit and 64-bit versions of the package

Download both from Microsoft here:

**32-bit** : https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=5555

**64-bit** : https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=14632